# Where do I check the results of Mahout's jester example?

Tags: mahout, collaborative-filtering

After I run: mahout org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.example.jester.JesterRecommenderEvaluatorRunner

```
mahout org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.example.jester.JesterRecommenderEvaluatorRunner
Running on hadoop, using HADOOP_HOME=/usr
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
11/04/23 23:52:18 WARN driver.MahoutDriver: No org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.example.jester.JesterRecommenderEvaluatorRunner.props found on classpath, will use command-line arguments only
11/04/23 23:52:18 INFO file.FileDataModel: Creating FileDataModel for file src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/example/jester/jester-data-1.csv
11/04/23 23:52:18 INFO file.FileDataModel: Reading file info...
11/04/23 23:52:18 INFO file.FileDataModel: Read lines: 7074
11/04/23 23:52:18 INFO model.GenericDataModel: Processed 7074 users
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Beginning evaluation using 0.9 of FileDataModel[dataFile:/usr/local/mahout-distribution-0.4/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/example/jester/jester-data-1.csv]
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO model.GenericDataModel: Processed 2155 users
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO slopeone.MemoryDiffStorage: Building average diffs...
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Beginning evaluation of 855 users
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Starting timing of 855 tasks in 4 threads
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 2ms
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 9MB / 56MB
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 0 cases
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Evaluation result: 154472.97849261735
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO jester.JesterRecommenderEvaluatorRunner: 154472.97849261735
11/04/23 23:52:19 INFO driver.MahoutDriver: Program took 740 ms
```

No idea where to check the results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That *is* the result. You are running an evaluation on one recommender implementation, one which scores how well that one recommender predicts ratings. It shows the average difference between actual and predicted rating.

What result are you looking for?

However something looks pretty wrong here: 154472.97849261735 is way too large. When I run it, I get an average difference of 3.41 (on a scale of 10).

I would run with the [latest code from Subversion](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Version+Control), ideally. 0.4 is 6 months old, although I don't know of any bugs here. You also don't need to run this via the driver program, though it works.

Really I suspect your jester-data-1.csv file is wrong somehow. Best to follow up on user@mahout.apache.org.